# setInterval to set text on Text Area

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

I'm taking a string that is inside of a textarea, splitting it into an array by the delimiter "=====\n" and then printing out each index of that array inside the textarea every 250ms. The problem is that the webpage seems to be freezing every time I click the button that starts all of this.

I'm very new to JS and would appreciate any advice/help.

Here is what I tried.

Method to be called by setInterval: (theStage is the textarea)

```
function start(){
var frames = theStage.value.split("=====\n");
    while(true){
        for(var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++){
            theStage.value = frames[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Timer:

```
function changeFrame(){
    var time = setInterval(start, 250);
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `while(true)`... Your setInterval will recall the function for you.
Try running it without the `while` loop.

Comment: Could I ask you another question if you have the time, what I was more so looking for with this code was to have it print out each index of the array with 250ms intervals between them..., as in frames[0]...wait 250ms... frames[1]...wait 250ms.... it looks to me like its rushing to the end immediately. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I updated my answer, again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `while(true)`... Your setInterval will recall the function for you. Try running it without the `while` loop.

UPDATE:

Based on your above comment, you're trying to go to step over the array every `250ms`.
To achieve this, you want to use setTimeout instead!

Here's how:

```
function start(){

    var frames = theStage.value.split("=====\n");
    var i = 0, l = frames.length;
    (function iterator() {
        theStage.value = frames[i];

        if(++i<l) {
            setTimeout(iterator, 250);
        }
    })();
};

start();
```